# Have multiple parameters in a WHEN part of a SQL Update Statement

Tags: sql, select, sql-update, case

I need to write a sql update statement without repeating the parameter on the WHEN part of the query, below query works fine however I would like to group the related parameters together, this is how the current query looks like

```
UPDATE [dbo].[VIPCO_UserSTCRelation]
   SET [UserAccessId] = CASE [STC_Code]
    WHEN '841900' THEN 21
    WHEN '841300' THEN 9
    WHEN '841400' THEN 21
    WHEN '841305' THEN 21
    WHEN '846000' THEN 38
    WHEN '841002' THEN 38
    WHEN '841000' THEN 40
    WHEN '841005' THEN 40
    WHEN '841004' THEN 40
    END
```

for example I would like to use an IN to group bundle all the STCs belong to 40 together, I have tried the below part, but no joy

`WHEN IN ('841000','841005','841004') THEN 40`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the conditions from the `case` to the `when` part of the expression:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[VIPCO_UserSTCRelation]
SET [UserAccessId] = CASE 
    WHEN [STC_Code] = '841300' THEN 9
    WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('841900', '841400', '841305') THEN 21
    WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('846000', '841002') THEN 38
    WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('841000', '841005', '841004') THEN 40
END
```

Comment: Dear sir, Why don't you group `21` value into one group?

Comment: @Anonymous: ah yes you are correct, I modified my answer accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by this way

```
UPDATE [dbo].[VIPCO_UserSTCRelation]
   SET [UserAccessId] = CASE
    WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('841900', '841400', '841305')  THEN 21
    WHEN [STC_Code] = '841300' THEN 9
    WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('846000', '841002') THEN 38
    WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('841000', '841005', '841004') THEN 40
    END
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Ronny Mahlangu

Answer (score 1):

```
IIF([STC_Code] IN ('841000','841005','841004'), 40,
               IIF([STC_Code] IN ('841300'), 9
))
```

IIF will solve your problems and with the right indantation it can be readable.

Also for case

```
CASE
  WHEN [STC_Code] IN ('841000','841005','841004') THEN 40
```